# How to get only audio frequency and decibles from FFTBasedSpectrumAnalyzer project?

Tags: android, audio, frequency

I'm using [FFTBasedSpectrumAnalyzer](https://github.com/sommukhopadhyay/FFTBasedSpectrumAnalyzer). 
I'm new to FFT. How do I continuously listen to external audio and calculate only frequency and decibels.

Are there any other simple libraries where I can get frequency and decibels continuously.

Answer (score 0):

How do I continuously listen to external audio:
Check the "RecordAudio.doInBackground()" - function it does it already.

Calculate frequency and decibels:
If FFTBasedSpectrumAnalyzer is the source for this [program](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xyz.fft), then the program already does it for you, only not in decibels. The frequency you can see on the x-axis. The y-axis represents the decibels. If you want it in numbers you just have to calculate it from the numbers you get from the software library. Roughly speaking the calculation should be something like this:

> 20 * log10(number/fft_win_size)

.